Ubuntu 20.04 upload folder permissions
Server (Ubuntu 20.04) has UploadFolder, so anyone could upload.
UploadFolder permissions are as follows
drwxrwsr-x 4 root      www-data

While uploading, the script is creating sub-folder and sub-subfolder inside UploadFolder. The uploaded file should be landed in sub-subfolder.
Everything is working as supposed to be. As a result, on the uploading attempt, server receives subfolder and sub-subfolder with permissions as follows accordingly
drwxrwxrwx 3 www-data www-data
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data

So, as far as I understand, file should be uploaded, but it's not.
The script by itself is 100% good, since it does the job on the another server.
What is wrong here?
How to make upload works?

For folders the permission should be 755, and for files 644

The correct permissions for web server (i.e. Apache or Nginx) is like that for folders the permission should be 755, and for files 644,

755 folders will be shown as drwxr-x-r-x
and 644 files will be shown as -rw-r--r--

Use these commands to make it happen, go to the server root (usually /var/www/html/) and first run:
sudo chmod -R 644 ./*

this applies 644 to all files, then do:
find ./ -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 755

which applies 755 to all folders.

Will such permissions allow to upload visitor's files to the upload folder?
